# How do I input values for this function and output the power(of input values)

Tags: javascript, performance, function, input, global-variables

Code snippet:
Question: returns "undefined" on browser console,how do I get the code to input a and b and output power?

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
function power(a,b)
{
    if (b === 0) {
        console.log("power = 1");
    } else if (b === 1) {
        console.log("power = a");
    } else {
        return math.power(a, b-1);
    }
    console.log("Power");
}
```

Comment: Did you call the function? Also you are only returning a value if `b` is higher than `1`.

Comment: Let's just address the elephant in the room and point out that `power(a, b)` is just an alias to `Math.pow`. In any case `function power(a, b){ return Math.pow(a, b); }` should suffice.

Comment: If you've called the function, there should be an error message in the console, `math` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

did you call your function with required values? i.e

```
power(a,b);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;

function power(a,b)
{
    if (b === 0) {
        console.log("power = 1");
    } else if (b === 1) {
        console.log("power = a");
    } else {
        return math.power(a, b-1);
    }
    console.log("Power");
}

//call function 
power(a,b);
```

Comment: Give enough explanation about your answer.